# Probability of getting no two consecutive successes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

The probability of success in any trial of a random experiment is $\frac{1}{3}$. If $p_n$ be the probability of getting no two consecutive successes in n trials of the given experiment then prove that $p_n = \frac {2}{3}p_{n-1} + \frac {2}{9}p_{n-2}$

My attempt : Getting two consecutive successes in n trials can be obtained in $n-1$ ways. Hence probability of getting no two consecutive success in n trials is $ p_n = 1- \frac {1}{9}(n-1) $.  I am not sure if this is correct. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: I think knowing combinatorics may help here.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I think that your comment needs a definition of "knowing combinatorics" to be understood, that, depending on this definition, said comment will be either trivially true or trivially false, and that in neither case it can help solving the question in any way. Agreed?

Comment: probability and combinatorics happen together all the time @Did

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Ah, so we are going towards "neither true nor false, just empty"?

Answer (score 2):

The way it is written, you must proceed by recurrence only.

So suppose you are given a sequence of $n$ trials with no consecutive successes. Denote $F$ for failure and $S$ for success. Then, this sequence can end in one of the following two ways: $F,S$. Now, one of two things can happen.

1: A sequence of $n-1$ trials, with no consecutive successes, and the last one is a failure. The number of chances of this happening is $\frac 23 p_{n-1}$ clearly.

2: A sequence of $n-2$ trials, with no consecutive successes, the last one of our sequence is a success and the second last one has to be a failure, otherwise we would have two consecutive successes. Hence, the probability of this happening is $p_{n-2} \times \frac 13 \times \frac 23 = \frac 29 p_{n-2}$.

Since one of the above must happen, and they are disjoint, we have $$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red] {p_n = \frac{2}{3}p_{n-1} + \frac 29 p_{n-2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Keep track of 2 things: the chance that we made it to time $n$ r with a success at time $n$, and that we made it to time $n$ without a success at time $n$.  These 2 quantities obey an update rule for going from $n\to n+1$, from which you can work out your answer.